# WordPress Taxonomy Template Pagination Issue

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, pagination, taxonomy

After dedicating hours on this issue I finally decided to ask the community about the problem I am facing. This issue itself is somewhat interesting and strange.

I created a custom taxonomy template and while I am using the default wordpress loop I am facing issues in Pagination. **The posts in every page are coming randomly**.

So lets say if I am on page `1` of the taxonomy pagination it shows me `2` posts and if I go to page `2` it shows me `4` posts then `2` and then `3` posts per page ..

I have set the `posts_per_page` as 6 using `pre_get_posts` action on my `functions.php` file ..

I am giving the brief codes below ..

**TEMPLATE FILE**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php
global $wp_query;
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
?>

<div <?php post_class('main-section page-inner-wrapper'); ?>>
    <?php get_template_part('talent_filter', 'talent_filter.php'); ?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>                                       

                <!-- POST HTML -->

            <?php endwhile;  ?>

            <!-- PAGINATION BEGIN -->
            <nav class="navigation pagination" role="navigation">
                <?php 
                    echo paginate_links( array(
                        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
                        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                        'current' => $paged,
                        'prev_text' => __( '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>', 'bridge' ),
                        'next_text' => __( '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>', 'bridge' ),
                        'before_page_number' => '<span class="meta-nav">' . __( '', 'bridge' ) . ' </span>',
                        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
                    ) );
                ?>
            </nav>
            <!-- PAGINATION END -->

      <?php endif; ?>   
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**FUNCTIONS IN `function.php`**

```
function my_post_queries( $query ) {
  // do not alter the query on wp-admin pages and only alter it if it's the main query
    if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()){

    // alter the query for the home and category pages 

        if( is_tax( 'talent_groups' ) ) {
            $query->set('posts_per_page', 6);
            $query->set('posts_per_archive_page', 6);
            $query->set('orderby', 'date');
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_post_queries');

// Solves Pagination Pages 404's
add_filter( 'option_posts_per_page', 'tdd_tax_filter_posts_per_page' );
function tdd_tax_filter_posts_per_page( $value ) {
return (is_tax('talent_groups')) ? 1 : $value;
}
```

Comment: I would start by removing all plugins and also seeing if the results change based on the theme you are using. It is possible that something else is hooking 'pre_get_posts' and it is clobbering your 'posts_per_page' setting.   You could look at the 'request' that was actually issued.  I think you can use something like <?php echo $GLOBALS['wp_query']->request; ?> to see if the numbers look right.

Comment: Well, I have checked the plugins thing. Not sure about the theme though, I am using bridge theme its the most selling, should have such bug but let me check ..

Comment: What is output if you put "var_dump($wp_query->request);"  right before the loop after you test "if (have_posts() )".   Look at the LIMIT statement at the end of the query  if it says anything other than 6 as the last number then something is messing with your posts_per_page  or your my_post_queies isn't executing the way you think.

Comment: Thanks mate, the `LIMIT` was set to 6 but the mysql query made me detect the problem in my code ..